# Scraping secured page with php curl?

Tags: php, curl, networking, web-scraping, reverse-proxy

Trying to scrape a page with php curl. But I receive **time out error** every time I hit that URL. The URL which I am trying, it opens in browser but not through my php curl request.

My request is identical to the one which is passed in browser. I use **Burp suite** to get the request and response information. I also set the header which is required.

**I am assuming that it is happening due to my server ip is different that what is being expected from that URL.**

Could anyone let me know why this could happen. I don't have great knowledge about **networking**. Hence struggling with **scraping** the page.

Additionally I would like to let you know guys that this URL **changes its URL** after successful on load using JavaScript. For example: http://example.tld/page?p1=234&p2=532 becomes http://example.tld/api/page. **I want to know if this could be the reason or it is Server IP OR something else.**

Below is the code which I am trying.

```
function get_web_page( $url ){
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,    // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900P Build/LRX21T) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Mobile Safari/537.36", // who am i
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,      // timeout on connect

        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array(
            "Pragma: no-cache",
            "Cache-Control: no-cache",
            "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1",
            "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900P Build/LRX21T) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Mobile Safari/537.36",
            "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
            "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
            "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9",
            "Cookie: JSESSIONID=0C072792B81AAAC43110DE7106E4F30C", 
            "Connection: close",
        ),
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 30,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,    // Disabled SSL Cert checks
    );
    /*$last_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);.*/
    $ch      = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $header['errno']   = $err;    
    $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
    $header['content'] = $content;
    return $header;
}
```

Comment: Hardcoding `Cookie: JESESSONID`? Sounds weird.

Comment: Thanks @Raptor. Hardcoding Cookie: JESESSONID. It may be the issue?

Comment: JSESSIONID is a cookie in J2EE web application which is used in session tracking. It is generated when creating a session. Thus, do not hardcode it.

Comment: @Raptor Thanks for the suggestion. I will look into it. Anything else you want to point out within the code. What you thing about IP, it may be the issue?

Comment: What if `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` is set to `true` ?

Comment: I don't reach to that url, it gives timeout error(in all case) even if followlocation is true!

Comment: It could be some restrictions at the destination server, e.g. allows only certain user agent. Also, the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` is unnecessary. Can't really tell if we cannot test it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The URL works on browser but it does not work with my curl script. Why `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` is unnecessary.

Comment: The HTTP header is generated automatically by cURL request.

Comment: Okay So there is no need to send `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` in every request. So what are mandatory things need to be passed in curl to work properly. Thanks

Comment: You can read the documentation of `curl_init()` in PHP.net